# git directory diff : Bad file number

Tags: git

I am doing a folder diff between two git branches but I am getting this error: Bad file number

This is the command:

```
git difftool --dir-diff master..origin/BranchA
```

There is no issue when I diff a file with difftool across two branches. This only occurs when I do the folder diff.

This link mentions the Bad file number, I have made those changes but this doesn't solve my problem:
http://theo.im/blog/2012/10/27/directory-comparison-for-git-difftool/

The error is coming from:
    ....libexec/git-core\git-difftool line 464

The Repo is quite large. Could this cause a timeout and if so is the wait time configurable?

git version 1.9.4.msysgit.0

Windows 7 professional

Comment: What diff utility are you using? could it be returning immediately instead of when it is closed? Also, if this is Beyond Compare, do you have another instance running? If so, try using either BComp.exe or BComp.com. The latter will always wait for the comparison to complete.

Comment: @Hasturkun The Diff tool is Beyond Compare. There is no other instance running. I've tried BComp.exe or BComp.com as suggested but no luck.

Comment: It looks like it returns early because it gets the "Bad file number" error

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the "Bad file number" error is output because git-difftool is trying to clean up the temporary directory, and a file is locked. i.e. if the diff utility process returns, but is still running (and having some file open, since the windows default is to lock open files), cleanup will fail. AFAICT, this should work with bcomp since version 4.0.0.16821 (according to the [changelog](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=v4betalog). If it doesn't, you might want to try [their forum](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/forumdisplay.php?46-Version-Control)

Comment: @Hasturkun Trying this out but having some difficulties with git config atm.

Comment: @Hasturkun. I got the config issues resolved and it's working with bc4/BCcompare.exe, like this:difftool.bc4.path="C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 4/BCompare.exe"
mergetool.bc4.path="C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 4/BCompare.exe"

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update my .gitconf with following setting:

```
cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BComp.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

Replacye by:

`cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BCompare.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\`"

BCompare uses 2 commands: BComp.exe and BCompare.exe. Use the later one.